# Networking only when network in use (android)

Tags: android, android-networking

Is there a way to listen to the 3G/WIFI radios so that if another app starts using the internet (turns on those radios) we can start utilizing the radios for our queued calls?

Comment: I suspect somebody down-voted because there are plenty of questions (with answers) on StackOverflow about checking change of network state. You can just use a `BroadcastReceiver`. Look at the standard `ACTION_` constants for `Intent` and also those for `WifiManager`.

Comment: The problem is trying to find a unifying method that covers all network radios.

Comment: Actually I was wrong about looking at the `Intent` actions. You need to be looking at `ConnectivityManager` which has `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. It covers everything.